# PDF display garbled in Chrome

Tags: linux, google-chrome, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I see this when clicking a link to a PDF stored on Amazon S3 in Chrome:
[image]

If I download the same URL using wget or follow the same link in Firefox the PDF displays normally.

It looks like Chrome is not interpreting the file as a PDF. Is the problem with the PDF file or with Chrome? The PDF file was generated by wkhtmltopdf 0.12.3 (with patched qt) on Arch Linux.

Edit: it seems like a problem with the PDF because when I use `file` to identify the format it returns "data" whereas a normal PDF returns something like "PDF document, version 1.6".

Comment: If you download and use a text editor.to view does it start with %PDF-1.4 or is there anything in the file before that?

Comment: In emacs it fires up a converter that tries to convert it to PNG but fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I was using PDFKit to generate PDFs with the verbose option on. The verbose option somehow put all of `stdout` inside the PDF itself which caused Chrome to not detect the file as a PDF.